# SQL/SpatiaLite: how to declare a column as geometry?

Tags: geometry, spatialite

I am creating a new table through a SQL query from a spatial table:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeShapes AS
SELECT ash.id, ash.Geometry
FROM AllShapes ash
WHERE ash.id = 30
```

However, this returns a "normal" table, so when I try to load it in a GIS program (QGIS), it doesn't show the geometry. How do I declare that the geometry column contains, well, geometry?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to create a "non-spatial" table, and then add the `Geometry` column to it.

Then, you can insert data into your table.

It can't be done in one single step (`create table as select`). From [the documentation](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/new-geom.html):

> Creating a Geometry-type at the same time the corresponding table is
>   created isn't allowed.  You always must first create the table, then
>   adding the Geometry-column in a second time and as a separate step.

```
CREATE TABLE test_geom (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  measured_value DOUBLE NOT NULL);

SELECT AddGeometryColumn('test_geom', 'Geometry', 4326, 'POINT', 'XY');
```

Also, take into account that you may want to use [spatial indexes](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/rtree.html) to improve the performance

```
SELECT CreateSpatialIndex('test_geom', 'Geometry');
```