# Syntax error while using centroid function within the RotateCoords function in Spatialite Query

Tags: sql, sqlite, spatialite

```
CREATE TABLE rotated_bus AS SELECT AO_id,
RotateCoords(ST_Centroid(Geometry) FROM Substation, 45.00) AS Geometry FROM Busbar;
```

I am trying to rotate a line geometry (Busbar) by passing the centroid of a polygon geometry (Substation) inside the RotateCoords Function. After running the above query, I am getting an error “near FROM syntax error”. What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Is `Substation` a table or a column name? If it is a table, how is it related to `Busbar`?

Comment: Substation is a Table, And substations "Substn_ID" = Busbars "Ao_ID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE rotated_bus AS
SELECT Busbar.AO_id,
       RotateCoords(ST_Centroid(Substation.Geometry), 45) AS Geometry
FROM Busbar
JOIN Substation ON Busbar.AO_id = Substation.Substn_ID
```

Alternatively, use a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) (subqueries must be complete queries inside an extra pair of parentheses):

```
CREATE TABLE rotated_bus AS
SELECT AO_id,
       (SELECT RotateCoords(ST_Centroid(Geometry), 45)
        FROM Substation
        WHERE Substn_ID = Busbar.AO_id
       ) AS Geometry
FROM Busbar
```

Comment: Also, take into account that you can't `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` on SpatiaLite to get a working geometric table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744932/sql-spatialite-how-to-declare-a-column-as-geometry